# Find all positive integers $n$ such that
$n^6 + 6n^5 + 4n^4 - n^2 - n + 2$ is prime.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Find all positive integers $n$ such that
$n^6 + 6n^5 + 4n^4 - n^2 - n + 2$ is prime.

Any idea to start? How to factorize them out to get some ideas?

Comment: it hasn't any rational root, so it's not a trivial problem. Also, $p(-1) = -1$, so that you can't argue something like "the polynomial is never prime because is always divisible by this number" (it won't work when tested in -1). Also, $n=1$ gives a prime (eleven).

Comment: Why $-1$ since $n$ is positive?

Comment: if, say, $12 \mid p(n)$ for all positive $n$, then $12 \mid p(-1) $ also. If you know a bit of modular arithmetics this is because $p(-1) \equiv p(11) \pmod{12} $, since $p$ is polynomial. But I realized in the end of the comment that you can use also $p(1) = 11$ which is prime and avoid this overly complicated argument.

Comment: How do you know you have the correct polynomial?

Comment: This is irreducible and gcd(f(0),f(1))=1. By the Bouniakowsky conjecture there are infinite n which give prime numbers.  There is no start for analysis, this is an unsolved problem since 1857.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I just wrote a program on c++ and it seems like there could be a lot :)
There are two alternatives:

1. You got the wrong polynomial;
2. Your teacher is better than my pc with calculations.

Here it is the code I used:

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int test_prime(long long int x) {
    int d;
    float ths = sqrt(x);
    for(d=2; d<= ths; d++) {
        if(x%d == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

long long int poly(long long int n) {
    return pow(n,6)+6*pow(n,5)+4*pow(n,4)-pow(n,2)-n+2;
}


int main()
{
    int n,N;
    cout <<"enter the maximum N you want to test" << endl;
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Here it is the list of n that produce prime numbers:" << endl;
    for(n=0; n<=N;n++) {
        if( test_prime(poly(n)) == 1 ) {
           cout << n << " produces " << poly(n) << endl;
       } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It returns quite many primes, and after that it goes out of memory:

```
0 produces 2
1 produces 11
5 produces 36847
13 produces 7168631
17 produces 32990491
19 produces 62423381
21 produces 111048191
25 produces 304296227
27 produces 475638941
33 produces 1531022891
35 produces 2159398117
53 produces 24705093151
57 produces 37948820291
63 produces 68541129281
69 produces 117393014831
71 produces 139027301641
79 produces 261705587921
107 produces 1585407762541
115 produces 2434441786037
123 produces 3632659864061
143 produces 8911441858321
151 produces 12327007462361
153 produces 13332932524451
159 produces 16770104782241
181 produces 36331706896031
191 produces 50081719101121
195 produces 56677858561157
207 produces 80960042697041
233 produces 164137834805491
235 produces 172737657543917
253 produces 268490472955751
277 produces 461537975400191
289 produces 594746103578411
291 produces 619785617090021
297 produces 700235587063091
299 produces 728911546022701
303 produces 789205631796401
321 produces 1114524100418891
349 produces 1838101582558151
361 produces 2250169250734451
379 produces 3010708332794621
395 produces 3856033675042957
411 produces 4890522937999901
417 produces 5333723407128491
429 produces 6320988884994071
433 produces 6682102616188091
437 produces 7060246828863391
```

NB: For the non-programmer guys like me, remember you can copy and paste the code for example [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler), then click on "run" above and use the program in the window below. Enjoy!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture  .....anyway, as this polynomial leads to no nice answer, it seems likely that it is incorrect; no source is given

Comment: A faster way to evaluate a polynomial is [Hernon's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

Comment: meanwhile, I use GMP with C++, it is pretty good. It checks primes by Miller-Rabin

Comment: @adam: well, when it has degree six, faster for me means faster to write XD but you are right! What is GMP Will? SO Bunyakovsky conjecture basically says that if the problem is not " trivial" as we were saying above, then there are infinitely many primes? Lol

Comment: Hehe, fair enough! :-)

Comment: there is typo in line 16

Comment: which typo? I'll edit

Comment: the polynomial is $n^6 + 6n^5+4n^4-n^2-n+2$

Comment: You are right. I have run again the program, I am posting the new results. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but it stil typo

Comment: pow(n,6) + 6*pow(n,5) + 4*pow(n,4) - pow(n,2) - n + 2

Comment: and in for at last, it must : for(n=1, ...) since $n$ is positive integer

Comment: @user where did you get the polynomial?

Comment: from my friends

Comment: i'm starting to suspect a troll here

Comment: nah, there is no typo again

Comment: and now, the answer is infinitely prime?

Comment: Look at the first comment of @WillJagy: there is a conjecture stating that if the leading coefficient is positive, there is at least one prime value, and it is irreducible over the integers, then it has infinite prime values.