# Do you expect a generic polynomial to produce "the right amount of prime numbers"?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Take a polynomial with integer coefficients $p(x)$.
Some of them, like $p(x) = x^2$ or $p(x) = x^3-x$ produce very few prime numbers, while some others $p(x) = x^2-x+41$ seem to produce lots of them.

If you start from a simple example $p(x) = ax+b$ with $a,b$ coprime, since primes are evenly distributed among mod a classes, we will have that the probability of $p(x)$ being prime is the same as the probability of $x$ being prime. Do you think this is true for generic polynomials, or there is some intrinsic bias in increasing the degree toward being more composite/ more prime? For me that I am not expert, this seems an incredibly hard question. I don't want necessarily to be quantitative, but for example a weak formulation could be

$$   \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{ \log |\{x\le n: p(x) \text{ is prime } \}|}{\log(n) } = 1 $$

Comment: I think you want to search for *Bateman-Horn*.

Comment: This is an incredibly hard question. :-) Even the question of 'is $p(n)$ prime infinitely often?' for irreducible polynomials $p$ of degree $\gt 1$ is wide-open AFAIK; for instance take $p(n)=n^2+1$...

Comment: @Steven very hard to prove anything, yes, but there are widely-believed conjectures.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  this refers to a question in the last few minutes that Andrea answered; most likely the polynomial given there was not correctly transcribed, as it is irreducible and represents many primes.  I'll find the link. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3961922/find-all-positive-integers-n-such-thatn6-6n5-4n4-n2-n-2-is-pr/3961949#3961949

Comment: ok, so you are saying: we dont' know if they are infinite, you are asking for density? Take a seat, please.

Comment: @AndreaMarino to whom are you addressing your comment?

Comment: To steven stadnicki!

Comment: As Gerry mentions, this entire circle of questions is a special case of the Bateman-Horn conjecture, which allows for multiple polynomials being prime at the same time, not just a single polynomial, e.g., can $n^2 + 1$ and $n^3 - 2$ both be prime together for infinitely many $n$?  All such questions are completely out of reach except for a single polynomial of degree $1$ (Dirichlet's theorem).

Comment: You bring up the example $x^2 - x + 41$, which has the peculiar feature of taking lots of *initial* prime values at small integers.  This is a different issue from how often the polynomial takes prime values over long intervals of integers.  That "many initial values are prime" property is related to class numbers of quadratic fields: $x^2 - x + 41$ has discriminant $1 - 4(41) = -163$ and $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{-163})$ is the last imaginary quadratic field with class number $1$.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561/eulers-remarkable-prime-producing-polynomial-and-quadratic-ufds.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that's a different issue and it was just folklore: the Bateman-Horn conjecture seems exactly what I was looking for. I am very excited to try to apply this to the OP question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3961922/find-all-positive-integers-n-such-thatn6-6n5-4n4-n2-n-2-is-pr/3961949?noredirect=1#comment8170903_3961949. I am pleased by the degree factor in the denominator of the BH conjecture, but I was wondering if it is possible to estimate the numerator even not sharply, but significantly.

Comment: By "numerator" do you mean the infinite product over primes?  Some discussions about that product  are on Mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214873/bateman-horn-conjecture-continued

Comment: yep! oh-oh, seems like i should get back to study algebraic number theory to understand this stuff. It's a pity I have never really get into this. However, I imagine that the answer is  "no, there is no obvious estimate of the product, but there are clever ones", right? Thank you :)

Comment: @AndreaMarino  you should begin a comment with an @ sign followed by the username of the person you are addressing. You will be offered a little window with a choice of full names (if more than one matches the letters you have typed so far), click on the correct one and it fills in the correct username. As I did with your name above

Comment: @AndreaMarino Sorry for coming back to this so late! I wasn't meaning to be quite so dismissive with my comment — more just suggesting that while there is a lot of heuristic evidence and conjecture on the density of prime values of polynomials, so little is known for sure that we can't even assert infinitely many primes in the simplest cases. In other words, that your speculation is right and that the question is very hard indeed.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: no problem at all :) to be honest, I am very happy with what I have discovered and I thank you all. I'd accept an answer explaining me some of the main heuristic ideas behind BH conjecture, or if this is too much, some of the tools.